# Python: how to group together trips in a given distance and time apart?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that contains data of trips made by users.
The dataframe is something like that

```
dftS:

Trip    XO       YO           XD            YD           StartingTime
1   -33.55682 -70.78614   -33.44007     -70.65520     2014-12-30 22:30:00
2   -33.49097 -70.77741   -33.48908     -70.76263     2014-12-30 18:30:00
3   -33.37108 -70.67110   -33.73425     -70.76278     2014-12-30 18:00:00
```

I want to group together couple of trips if both origin (`XO,YO`) and destination (`XD,YD`) points of the two trips are at most `D=1km` meters apart and if they have the same origin and destination zone, and if their starting times are at most `T=30min` minutes apart. In order to achieve this result I am doing the following:

```
l=list()
N = len(dftS)
for i in range(0,N-1):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        dt = abs(dftS.HoraIni[i]-dftS.HoraIni[j])
        if dt.total_seconds() < deltat.total_seconds():
            if haversine(dftS.XO[i], dftS.YO[i], dftS.XO[j], dftS.YO[j]) < 1:
                if haversine(dftS.XD[i], dftS.YD[i], dftS.XD[j], dftS.YD[j]) < 1:
                    g=list()
                    g.append(i)
                    g.append(j)
                    l.append(g)
```

In order to count the distance between two points I am using the so-called haversine function

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
```

I am wondering if there is a more compact way to solve this problem using Python

Comment: Besides some style stuff, I don't think there is a better way (for instance, separate the three `if` that check the matching in a function to get easier to read code and less cyclotonic complexity). IMHO it is ok to use the haversine function. I think you have a small bug though, since you are adding to `g` the `i` index every time you find a match. So, I think you should replace `g.append(i)  g.append(j)` by `g.append((i,j))`, if you want a list of pairs. You could also make `l` a dictionary and put `l[i] = []` and append to `l[i]` all the `j`s.

Comment: You can't group on the basis of distances between two points.
What if third point is in 1 km from second? Add to this group?
For grouping you have to calculate some variable equal for all points in a group.